# Would using CXF instead of Axis for Restfull SOAP call decouple client from changes in wsdl?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cxf, apache-axis, restful-url

Currently I am using Axis for Restfull SOAP calls to Rally's Web Service, but the application breaks every time there is a change in wsdl. Would switching to CXF fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The point of a WSDL is that it's a contract. Client applications are meant to break if there's a change to the schema.

If you want something less tightly coupled, you can disable schema validation (some changes will still break things though) or use something more flexible like JSON.

Oh and there's no such thing as 'RESTful SOAP'. REST and SOAP are alternatives.

Comment: Yep, REST and SOAP are alternatives, but as a sub-alternative one can use REST to return XML, so one can specify XSD per REST operation. That is handy is you want to benefit from types and strict checking.

Comment: Can I disable schema validation in Axis 1.4, that could fix this issue? I googled about this, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Doesn't look like it from what I can see, sorry.